# How to write text over a drawn canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i have drawn over a ribbon with the code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('draw-ribbon');
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(300, 0);
ctx.lineTo(260, 75);
ctx.lineTo(300, 150);
ctx.lineTo(0, 150);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
```

got this:

[image]

after this i have tried `filltext()` but didn't work i want to achieve this:

[image]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Drawing_text_using_a_canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be not working because the text color is also red

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(300, 0);
ctx.lineTo(260, 75);
ctx.lineTo(300, 150);
ctx.lineTo(0, 150);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
ctx.font="30px Verdana";
ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
ctx.fillText("Text",50,80);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dvdyakonov/zFg5q/